# pg_dump works on Linux but gives Windows error

Tags: postgresql

I have PC-Windows 7 and run a daily dump from a PostgreSQL database that is on a Linux server. The commands executed are, via batch/commandline:

```
CD directory
SET PGUSER = user
SET PGPASSWORD = password
pg_dump --host = ipDoServer - p 5432 -v -f base.dump DatabaseName
```

The backup is running and suddenly on a table it stops. Pops up:

```
pg_dump: copying contents of table tableA
pg_dump: copying contents of table tableB
pg_dump: copying contents of table tableC
```

When it arrives at this table hangs, it does nothing else.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableC
(rsp_id integer serial, 
exp_id integer NOT NULL,
rsp_dataregistro date NOT NULL,
rsp_descricao text
)
With OIDS = FALSE);
```

It has only 9070 records.

If you perform pg_dump on a Linux machine, the dump is complete, without problems.

Does anyone know what the reason can be?

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` on the server and see what the `state`, `query` and (if you are on v10 or better) `wait_event`.

Comment: `- p 5432` should be `-p 5432` (no space between `-` and `p`)